# In TinyMCE, break a blockquote by hitting enter, like in Gmail

Tags: tinymce

We're using TinyMCE to create/edit email replies. As part of that, we'd like the ability to break a blockquote by hitting Enter in the middle of it, like you can do in Gmail. There don't appear to be any settings in TinyMCE to allow this. Have I missed it? Or is there a way programmatically to get this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adjusted an open source plugin, that sounds like it does what you require, to work with the latest version of TinyMCE.

You will need to copy the code to the plugin folder (see https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/ for details)

Demo http://fiddle.tinymce.com/7Qfaab/3

```js
/*
   Original Source: https://github.com/Tauop/tinymce_splitblockquote-plugin/blob/master/tiny_mce/plugins/splitblockquote/editor_plugin_src.js       
   NOTE: Modified by K Scandrett to work with current TinyMCE (~4.6.1)
*/ 

/* @author Patrick Guiran <pguiran@linagora.com>
 * @license GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 2
 * @copyright Copyright © 2010, Linagora, Patrick Guiran <pguiran@linagora.com>
 */

tinymce.PluginManager.add('SplitBlockquote', function(ed, url) {
  ed.on('click', function (e) {
    var parts, i, node, bq_node, openTags, closeTags, splitToken;

    if (e.keyCode != 13) {
      return; /* do nothing */
      }

    // get the top-most blockquote parent node
    function getMostTopBlockquote(n, r) {
      var last_bq = null;
      while (n) {
        if (n == r)
          break;
        if (n.nodeName === 'BLOCKQUOTE')
          last_bq = n;
        n = n.parentNode;
      }
      return last_bq;
    };



    function getClose(n, r) {
      // get the htnk "close-tag" of a node
      function getCloseTag(n) {
        if ( n.nodeName === 'FONT' && ed.settings.convert_fonts_to_spans) {
          return "</span>";
        } else {
          return "</" + n.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ">";
        }
      }

      var result = '';
      while (n) {
        if (n == r)
          break;
        result += getCloseTag(n);
        n = n.parentNode;
      }
      return result;
    }

    function getOpen(n, r) {
      // get the html "open-tag" of a node
      function getOpenTag(n) {
        var attr, copy;
        copy = n.cloneNode(false);
        copy.innerHTML = '';
        attr = ed.dom.getOuterHTML( copy )
                 .replace(new RegExp( '<'  + copy.nodeName, "i"), '')
                 .replace(new RegExp( '</' + copy.nodeName + '>', "i" ), '');
        return '<' + copy.nodeName.toLowerCase() + attr;
      };

      var result = '';
      while (n) {
        if (n == r)
          break;
        result = getOpenTag(n) + result;
        n = n.parentNode;
      }
      return result;
    }

    node = ed.selection.getNode();
    bq_node = getMostTopBlockquote(node, ed.getBody());
    if (!bq_node) // we aren't in a blockquote
      return;

    /* Create an unique splitToken */
    splitToken = '_$'+ (new Date()).getTime() + '$_';
    ed.selection.setContent(splitToken, {formar: 'raw'});
    parts = ed.getContent().split(splitToken);

    /* blockquote can handle DOM tree. So we have to close
     * and open DOM element correctly, and not wildly split
     * the editor content. Plus, openTags has to keep all
     * attributes to keep makeup of DOM elements, we split.
     */
    openTags = getOpen(node, bq_node);
    closeTags = getClose(node, bq_node);

    if (ed.settings.convert_fonts_to_spans && openTags != '') {
      /* juste convert </span> to </font>
       * if <font> are converted to <span>
       * as n.nodeName returns "FONT" for <span> node :/
       * @see tinymce.Editor.-_convertFonts() for more information
       */
      (function() {
        var font_count = ( openTags.match(/<font/ig) || [] ).length;
        for (i=0; i<font_count; ++i) {
          start_idx = parts[1].indexOf('</span>');
          if (start_idx != -1) {
            parts[1] = parts[1].substring(0, start_idx)
                     + '</font>'
                     + parts[1].substring(start_idx + 7);
          }
        }
      })();
    }

    /* Update the editor content :
     *  - part[0] : content before the selection, before split
     *  - closeTags : </tag> to close correctly html tags
     *  - </blockquote> : close the blockquote
     *  - <br id='__' /> : <br /> are converted to "<p> </p>". The id 
     *                     is used to change the location of the selection (cursor)
     *  - <blockquote> : open the new blockquote
     *  - openTags : re-open splited DOM nodes correctly
     *  - part[1] : content after the selection, before split
     */
    ed.setContent(   parts[0] + closeTags
                   + "</blockquote><br id=\"__\"><blockquote>"
                   + openTags + parts[1] );

    /* delete empty <p>aragraphe at the end of the first blockquote
     * and at the beginnig at the second blockquote.
     * Delete id attributes to */
    function clean_node(node) {
      var node_html;
      if ( node == null || node.nodeName != 'P' ) {
        return;
      }
      node_html = node.innerHTML.trim();
      if (node_html == '' || node_html == '<br mce_bogus="1">' || node_html == '<br>') {
        ed.dom.remove(node);
      }
    }

    bq_node = ed.getBody().getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
    for ( i = 0; i < bq_node.length; ++i) {
      if ( bq_node[i] == null ) { continue; } /* paranoiac mode */
      clean_node( bq_node[i].firstChild );
      clean_node( bq_node[i].lastChild );
      if ( bq_node[i].innerHTML.trim() === '' ) {
        ed.dom.remove( bq_node[i] );
      }
    }

   /* get the <br id="__"> element and put cursor on it */
    node = ed.dom.get('__');
    node.removeAttribute('id');
    ed.selection.select(node);
    ed.selection.collapse(true);

    /* Don't interpret <ENTER> again, to prevent a new "<p> </p>" to be added */
    return tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's not what we're looking for. Take an existing chunk of text within a blockquote. We need the ability to go within that block and, by hitting enter a couple of times, splitting that blockquote into two blockquotes.

Comment: This is great! I had to make one change; I had to change the event from 'click' to 'keyup' otherwise it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: This is amazing. I was having a problem on my mobile, where by I could not get out of a blockquote. But, using this plugin, after I hit enter twice, it breaks out after the 2nd ‘enter’! Great work. I will add this code without the plugin wrapper, because the mobile configuration does not allow custom plugins!

Answer (score 4):

**As of 2019, tinymce 5**

Add this to your config:

`end_container_on_empty_block: true`

Comment: This should be accepted answer now as of 2019 with tinymce v5